# How to get the location of a timestamp index? `data.columns.get_loc` seems to fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm iterating over a dataframe and I need to stop the iteration by the last Nth row.

`data.index[n]` works for getting the index but I'm having trouble to get its integer-location when the index is a datetime. It works with other indexes though.

```
> n = -5
> data.index[n]

Timestamp('2023-02-20 07:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

But when I try to get its location and the index is datatime, it doesn't work. It works with other datatypes though.

```
> n = -5
> data.columns.get_loc(data.index[t])

KeyError: Timestamp('2023-02-20 09:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: `data.index.get_loc(data.index[t])` ? Seems compare columns names by index in your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.columns` would output the columns of the data frame and not the index. The `get_loc` function works with indexes.

If you try `data.index.get_loc(data.index[t])`, that should give you the integer value of the location of that particular index.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).